# Accessing a private repo as a dependancy via appcenter

Tags: bitbucket, visual-studio-app-center

I have the following entry in my Podfile, which points to a private repository

> pod 'SDK', :git => 'https://username@bitbucket.org/private-repo.git', :branch => 'master'

When I run the build I receive the error

> Cloning into '/var/folders/24/8k48jl6d249_n_qfxwsl6xvm0000gn/T/d20191115-1307-zgatx7'...
>   fatal: could not read Password for 'https://username@bitbucket.org': terminal prompts disabled

How can I add my Bitbucket credentials into AppCenter so that it is able to pull in this repository?

I do not want to store my password in plain text.

Comment: Did you try with ssh ?